# robot_state_publisher has died, joint_state_publisher has died

Tags: robot-state-publisher, joint-state-publisher, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently learning urdf and am trying to make a two wheeled robot. I created a base link (chassis) and am trying to visualize it in rviz. To run the urdf file, i have also created a launch file. But when i run the launch file it gives me following error:

```
[ERROR] [1557809580.250795964]: Error reading Element value.
[robot_state_publisher-3] process has died [pid 5324, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/yash/.ros/log/25ab353a-7604-11e9-856b-7c2a31390882/robot_state_publisher-3.log].
log file: /home/yash/.ros/log/25ab353a-7604-11e9-856b-7c2a31390882/robot_state_publisher-3*.log

[joint_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 5323, exit code 1, cmd /home/yash/catkin_ws/src/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher __name:=joint_state_publisher __log:=/home/yash/.ros/log/25ab353a-7604-11e9-856b-7c2a31390882/joint_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/yash/.ros/log/25ab353a-7604-11e9-856b-7c2a31390882/joint_state_publisher-2*.log
```

The Launch file i am running is mentioned below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/2wheelrobot.urdf"/>

    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
        <param name="use_gui" value="False"/>
    </node>

    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/>
</launch>
```

I have searched for the solution on this forum but could not get any answers and hence i am posting this as a new question.
Sometimes I also get an error saying:

```
invalid <param> tag: cannot load command parameter robot_description
```

Can anyone please guide me with the rectification of this issue?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323094/robot_state_publisher-has-died,-joint_state_publisher-has-died/) by [Yash](https://answers.ros.org/users/40819/yash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asma](https://answers.ros.org/users/69003/asma/) on 2021-01-31**:
I have the same problem and I followed these steps but the error still exists..
when I type the command roslaunch everything works normal and then suddenly this happens:

```
[robot_state_publisher-3] process has died [pid 7068, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/robond/.ros/log/31078e02-63ff-11eb-8150-000c29954203/robot_state_publisher-3.log].
log file: /home/robond/.ros/log/31078e02-63ff-11eb-8150-000c29954203/robot_state_publisher-3*.log
```

I can't find the log file and i don't know why
can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have an issue because of your last error. The nodes `joint_state_publisher` and `robot_state_publisher` need as param `robot_description`, which is your robot `urdf` but your last error say that this parameter couldn't be loaded, meaning that both nodes can't be run too.

You just need to properly load the parameter `robot_description` :

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/2wheelrobot.urdf'"/>
```

---

**EDIT**

As @gvdhoorn said, you could use `check_urdf` to check if your `urdf` is well-formed (it's always a good practice). But I feel your error isn't due to a mistake in your urdf file because whenever I tried your example with a broken urdf file, the error directly pointed that out. The only times I managed to have the same error as you is when `$(find PACKAGE)` actually find the package you tell it to find but the urdf file isn't in this package. So you either have a typo in the name of your `urdf` file or you created a package within your workspace `urdf_tutorial` but forgot to source your package, since `urdf_tutorial` is also an official package that you've probably installed, the command `$(find urdf_tutorial)` do find the package but it's not yours, meanning it cannot find your file.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-14**:
@Delb: if `2wheelrobot.urdf` is not actually a `.xacro`, then using `xacro` shouldn't be necessary.

It could be that @Yash has an error in his urdf.

Perhaps running `check_urdf` would be a good idea?

**Comment by [Yash](https://answers.ros.org/users/40819/yash/) on 2019-05-14**:
Yes, it is not a xacro. Should i upload my URDF file?

**Comment by [Yash](https://answers.ros.org/users/40819/yash/) on 2019-05-17**:
@Delb I have created another package and i tried running the same launch file (name of the package is changed) and still it does not work.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-05-17**:\

> still it does not work

You need to give more informations than that please : is there an error (you should porovide the full error if it's different than the previous one) ? Also you didn't reply to us about the `check_urdf`, did it return errors or not ?

Moreover have you correctly sourced your catkin workspace as suggested ?

**Comment by [Yash](https://answers.ros.org/users/40819/yash/) on 2019-05-20**:
I am sorry for replying so late. But i resolved the error. And you guys were correct. The error was in the URDF File. I had forgotten to close the  tag. Thank You once again. You guys have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem and I followed these steps but the error still exists..
when I type the command roslaunch everything works normal and then suddenly this happens:

```
[robot_state_publisher-3] process has died [pid 7068, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/robond/.ros/log/31078e02-63ff-11eb-8150-000c29954203/robot_state_publisher-3.log].
log file: /home/robond/.ros/log/31078e02-63ff-11eb-8150-000c29954203/robot_state_publisher-3*.log
```

I can't find the log file and i don't know why
can someone help me please?

---

Originally posted by [asma](https://answers.ros.org/users/69003/asma/) with karma: 11 on 2021-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1